# When to use undef_method, and when to use remove_method?

Tags: ruby, reflection, methods, metaprogramming

I want to redefine a method, but avoid the warning associated with it. Should I use undef_method or remove_method to do so?

(Yes, redefining methods is a little hacky. I'm doing this because I have some memoization that I want to use when unit tests are being run, but not when the program itself is run.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-undef_method):

> **undef_method(symbol) → self**
>
> Prevents the current class from responding to calls to the named method. Contrast this with `remove_method`, which deletes the method from the particular class; Ruby will still search superclasses and mixed-in modules for a possible receiver.

So a `remove_method` like this:

```
class CC < C
  remove_method :m
end
```

is essentially the opposite of this:

```
class CC < C
  def m
  end
end
```

Where `def m` adds the method `m` to the class, `remove_method :m` removes `m`. But, if the super class has an `m` method, then that will still be used.

`undef_method`, OTOH, is more like this:

```
class CC < C
  def m
    raise 'No, you cannot do that.'
  end
end
```

So `undef_method` doesn't actually remove the method, it replaces the method with a special internal flag that causes Ruby to complain if you try to call that method.

Sounds like you're trying to replace an existing method and *replace* is semantically the same as a *remove* followed by an *add* so `remove_method` is probably more appropriate. However, if you want to be paranoid and make sure the replacement method is in place, then `undef_method` would be useful; or, if for some reason you need to remove the method in one place and add it in another, `undef_method` would at least tell you that you only did half the job whereas `remove_method` would either leave you with the super class's implementation (and possible strange bugs) or a rather confusing `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove a method in two easy ways. The drastic

```
Module#undef_method( )
```

removes all methods, including the inherited ones. The kinder

```
Module#remove_method( )
```

removes the method from the receiver, but it
leaves inherited methods alone.

See below 2 simple example  -

**Example 1 using *undef_method***

```
class A 
    def x
        puts "x from A class"
    end
end

class B < A
    def x
        puts "x from B Class"
    end
    undef_method :x
end

obj = B.new
obj.x
```

result  -
main.rb:15:in 
`': undefined method`x' for # (NoMethodError)

**Example 2 using *remove_method***

```
class A 
    def x
        puts "x from A class"
    end
end

class B < A
    def x
        puts "x from B Class"
    end
    remove_method :x
end

obj = B.new
obj.x
```

Result -
$ruby main.rb

x from A class