# Why am I unable to redefine an included class method after undefining it with undef in ruby?

Tags: ruby, module, rspec, ruby-mocha

I'm upgrading a Rails project and had included Mocha in an earlier version. It defined an `any_instance` method. The new(er) version of Rspec to which I'm upgrading also includes an `any_instance` method on all classes. I need to stick with Mocha for a little while while I upgrade everything so I don't have to change a bunch of tests, so I want to use the Mocha version of `any_instance`.

To do that, with Rspec, I'm *first* removing its own monkey pactching with `disable_monkey_patching!`. Then there's a `config.mock_with :mocha` call for Rspec that will cause mocha to define `any_instance` on `Class`. I know that monkey patching all classes is bad, but this question is actually a good lesson in why, but I'm curious about the results I'm seeing.

The above is some background about *why* I'm doing this. What follows is a minimal reproducible example that I can't explain and would appreciate insight on.

```rb
# Define a class
class A; end

# Define a module whose class methods I'd like to include in every class
module B
  module ClassMethods
    def a; end
  end
end

# Include method "a" in all classes
Class.send :include, B::ClassMethods

# Try it out!
A.a # <- works
```

Now I'll use undef to get rid of it, because that's what `disable_monkey_patching!` does:

```rb
Class.class_exec { undef a }
A.a # <- undefined method `a' for A:Class (NoMethodError) -- that's expected
```

But now I need to define a different method "a" for `Class`, which I'll define in module `C`.

```rb
module C
  module ClassMethods
    def a; end
  end
end

Class.send :include, C::ClassMethods
```

Here's the part that confuses me:

```rb
A.a # <- undefined method `a' for A:Class (NoMethodError)
```

This makes it seem like `undef` will permanently undefine it, but will not warn anyone when they try to define a method that will ultimately unusable. Why does this happen?

Tried on MRI 3.2.2 and 2.7.2

Comment: Does this older question help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11894308/479863

Comment: What absurd behavior!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `include` does not copy the methods into the receiver. It merely adds the included module to the list of modules that are traversed for [method lookup](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Lookup).

We can see this list by inspecting the [`ancestors`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) of `A`'s singleton class:

```
class A; end

A.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:A>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>,
#    Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When including `B::ClassMethods` into `Class`, this list changes accordingly:

```
Class.include(B::ClassMethods)

A.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:A>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>,
#    Class, B::ClassMethods, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that `B::ClassMethods` was added *after* `Class`.

Now, if you "undefine" method `a` via `undef` / `undef_method` with `Class` as its receiver, it will cause `Class` to prevent calls to that method by raising an (artificial) `NoMethodError` which also ends further method lookup: (I say "artificial" because the method is still there)

```
#<Class:A>  →  ...  →  Class  →  B::ClassMethods  →  ...
                         |             |
                       undef a         a
                                (never gets here)
```

If you include another module `C::ClassMethods` into `Class`, it will be added to the list, in front of `B::ClassMethods` but still *after* `Class`:

```
Class.include(C::ClassMethods)

A.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:A>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>,
#    Class, C::ClassMethods, B::ClassMethods, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And since `Class` still prevents `a` from being called, the new `a` method can't be reached either:

```
#<Class:A>  →  ...  →  Class  →  C::ClassMethods  →  B::ClassMethods  →  ...
                         |             |                   |
                       undef a         a                   a
                                (still not gets here)
```

---

For your actual problem (Mocha), you should first check the ancestors of your object(s) and identify where both `any_instance` methods are defined.

You can then add a monkey-patch into the right place via `include` / `prepend`.

Answer (score 3):

`undef` [is documented](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-undef) as follows:

> The `undef` keyword prevents the current class from responding to
> calls to the named methods.
>
> ```
> undef my_method
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> You may use `undef` in any scope. See also
> [Module#undef_method](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/Module.html#method-i-undef_method)

As such, it modifies the module it is "called" upon to not only remove a method defined it it, but to mark it so that it never respond to this method, even if it may be defined in a parent class or anywhere else in the inheritance chain.

The only way (I'm aware of) to remove this mark is to explicitly define a method in the module (or class) where you previously undefined the method. This works because by defining a method `a` on Class, we are reverting the "mark" added by `undef` or `Module#undef_method`

With your example, this could be achieved with:

```
class Class
  def a(...)
    super
  end
end
```

Here, we define a method `a` which accepts any arguments and just call `super` to forward the call along the ancestor chain, in this case either to `B::ClassMethods#a` or `C::ClassMethods#a`.

This alone should work out of the box. Now, we could even crank this up an additional notch and remove this newly created method `a` again, this time however with [`Module#remove_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Module.html#method-i-remove_method) which is documented as:

> Removes the method identified by symbol from the current class.

This will result in a state as if the method never existed (and was never undefined):

```
Class.remove_method :a
```

In the end, you can thus revert the effects of `undef` and `Module#undef_method` by defining a new method (with any accepted arguments and any method body) in the exact Module where it was previously undefined, and then removing it again.